# Need help installing Ubuntu16.04.2 desktop

Tags: system-installation, windows-vista

Downloaded 16.04.2 desktop from web. Created disc with Roxio. Searched questions but could not find installation instructions (for desktops) Currently running Vista on a Compac Presario SR2180NX How do I install Ubuntu using the file download OR the disc?
ty

Answer (score 0):

I think the disc will be better , that is how i installed Ubuntu.
you can also use USB memory stick
remember to backup any important document and  files

1- Restart your computer and wait for that first screen to pop up. Often, it'll say something like "Press F12 to Choose Boot Device" somewhere on the screen. Press that key now.
Give it a moment to continue booting, and you should see a menu pop up with a list of choices on it. Highlight your CD or USB drive and press Enter.

2-  then follow the instruction on the Ubuntu instillation